# Preimage of product connected sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X, A, B$ be connected topological spaces, and let $F: X \rightarrow A \times B$ be a continuous map. Assume also that $F^{-1}(\{a\} \times B)$ is not empty and connected for all $a \in A$, and similarly for $B$.

Now consider connected subsets $A'\subseteq A$ and $B'\subseteq B$, and let $X'=F^{-1}(A'\times B')$. If $\pi_A(F(X'))=A'$ and $\pi_B(F(X'))=B'$, where $\pi_\bullet$ is the projection map, can I conclude that $X'$ is connected?

Thanks

Edit: I am mainly interested in the case where $X=\mathbb R^n$, $A,B$ are subspaces, and $F$ is a product of projection maps.

Comment: Is not $\pi_A(F(X'))$ is always $A$? Do you need to write that as a hypothesis?

Comment: I meant- Is not $\pi_{A}(F(X'))$ is always $A'$? Because $F(X')=F(F^{-1}(A'\times B'))=A'\times B'$,

Comment: No because $F(X')=A' \times B'$ is not necessarily true (in fact, it's not true even under the hypothesis in the statement)

Comment: $F(X′)=A′×B′$ this is always true. Trying Proving it- for a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $A\subset Y$, $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$. What is not true is $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$. The true statement would be $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A)) $ .

Comment: It's true only if $f$ is surjective!

Comment: You are correct, I just messed it up.

Comment: A product of projection maps? Then $X$ must itself be some product? And then $F$ would be open, not necessarily closed, as a map. Projections are often not closed, and closedness of maps is not preserved by products (but openness is).

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that. What I meant is $X$ could be $\mathbb R^n$ (or $\mathbb P^n \setminus$ {appropriate set})..but yes $F$ is not closed.